# Can CsvHelper create "derived" rows, such as subtotals?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I've had a lot of recent success using CsvHelper to simplify many report exports, but I'm currently stumped as to how to output a "subtotal" row.

For instance, if my collection of strongly typed objects that I'm exporting are hours worked per day for an employee, I'd like to output a subtotal of all that employee's hours in a separate row.

Is that even possible with CsvHelper?  If it is, I suspect it's with a custom TypeConverter, but if that's the case, I'm not sure how to create a new row that isn't "based" one my strongly typed object.

Comment: I'd recommend moving away from CSV format if I were you. If it's intended for human consumption, I'd use HTML, PDF, or Open Office Spreadsheet (Excel 2007). If it's for programmatic consumption, then XML and JSON are better choices. CSV as a format just isn't very flexible.

Comment: The output format is part of contractual requirements and, while I appreciate your suggestion, it doesn't contribute much in terms of a solution.

Comment: It is not up to CsvHelper to know about your business data and the relations between each entity that it needs to export.I would be tempted to recommend you to insert the row manually in the collection yourself.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu if this is a subtotal or grand total type of row, then it would be still be have to be of the same type as the other objects, correct?  In this case it would have all values blank except "Subtotal."

Comment: Correct. Though this would "break" the CSV paradigm. If this is acceptable for you, you could output a second CSV containing only those subtotals. This would probably be a better solution.